# WebsitePanel - mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on line 38. Error connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, privileges, user-permissions, windows-server

I have migrated my files and database from cPanel (Linux server) to WebsitePanel (Windows servers). I have already installed and configured phpMyAdmin on WebsitePanel. But I got the following error message after migrated.

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on line 38. Error
>   connecting to mysql.

I'm pretty sure my database name, database user and password all are correct.

And after read a few forums, I realized that it might be the user privileges issue (not 100% sure).

I'm usually using cPanel to create the database user and it'll jump to manage user privileges after I created database user. But WebsitePanel is different. It doesn't have user privileges page. I'm not familiar with WebsitePanel.

[image]

Then, I think I should use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` after reading the similar issue. But I'm not sure how to do and combine with my code, I have been trying to figure this out for a few days. Am I in the correct direction? Please help...

```
$db_user='user'; // Database username
$db_pass='1234567'; // Database password
$db_host='localhost'; // Database host address
$db_name='database'; // Database name

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql.');  //line 38
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

use " NOT '

```
$db_user="user"; // Database username
$db_pass="1234567"; // Database password
$db_host="localhost"; // Database host address
$db_name="database"; // Database name

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql.');  //line 38
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```